# Using library paths in makefiles

Tags: gcc, makefile, cygwin, gnu-make

I have written a makefile like this:

```
HEADER = -I./cygdrive/c/cpros/kajj/source4
LIBB = -L./cygdrive/c/cpros/kajj/source1   -L./cygdrive/c/cpros/kajj/source2
LIBRA = -larith -ldekk

target : game.o 
    gcc $(HEADER)   $(LIBB)  $<  -o  $@  $(LIBRA)   

game.o : game.c 
    gcc -c  game.c
```

I have created my own static library and included the header file path and library path. When I execute my makefile it gives an error saying that
`/usr/lib/gcc` cannot find `-larith -ldekk`.

It is pointing to the lib/ directory but it is not over there: `-ldekk` and `-larith` are in source1 and source2 files respectively.

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `-L./cygdrive/c`, use `-L/cygdrive/c`. The dot makes the library path relative from the current directory, i.e. it will look for a `cygdrive` subfolder of the current folder instead of drive C.

Comment: your amazing tamas your just amazing.my project manager has assigned me these work and i'm very new to these makefiles just 9 days so i'm working on buti'm unable to figure out the error and the solution you gave its working too much right thank you once again tamas

Comment: tamas can you tell me the way to create a library a static library in makefiles i want a library named as gola.a and the .o files are gohh.o hola.o something like that i want that to be created but using the makefile how to write that code to create library file could you please tell me in the form of makefile

Comment: Please ask it in a different question on Stack Overflow and someone (maybe me) will answer there. It is best to keep one thread dedicated to one particular question.

Comment: What happens if the library is in a completely different path? 

Can I write something like -L~/foo1/foo2/

Thanks

Comment: I found a good answer here. They explain also the difference, in a makefile, between -l and -L 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519342/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-l-in-makefile

Answer (score 0):

My revised Makefile libraries line is:

```
LIBS=-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lrtlsdr -lpthread -lm
```

This solved the issue in a Raspberry Pi 4 running the latest Raspbain as of Dec 30, 2019