# How to link libconfig library for Raspberry Pi application

Tags: c, debian, raspberry-pi2, libconfig

Currently, I am modifying the C application for Raspberry Pi.
I build the application with this command:

```
make
```

Now I want to use [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/) library.
I have this below problems

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/yyyyy $ make
make --no-print-directory all-am
  CC       tools/xxxxx.o
  CCLD     tools/xxxxx
tools/xxxxx.c:2434: undefined reference to `config_read_file'
tools/xxxxx.c:2441: undefined reference to `config_lookup_string'
tools/xxxxx.c:2446: undefined reference to `config_destroy'
tools/xxxxx.c:2436: undefined reference to `config_destroy'
```

In the [libconfig manual](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html#Using-the-Library-from-a-C-Program) they said:

> To link with the library, specify ‘-lconfig’ as an argument to the
>   linker.

How can I link with `make` command?

Comment: show us your Makefile

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451342/library-path-in-makefiles

Comment: I am editting bluez app. http://www.bluez.org/download/ . Its make file is too large to post to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking into bluez's build system, I can offer simple approach - using environment variables.

```
# export CPPFLAGS='-I/home/oleksandr/software/libconfig/include'
# export LDFLAGS='-L/home/oleksandr/software/libconfig/lib/'
# ./configure
```

This should generate you Makefile, which you can use to compile bluez and link it with libconfig.

Comment: I Install libconfig-dev by: sudo apt-get install libconfig-dev. Then I run: dpkg -L libconfig-dev. But I can not find /include and /lib/ folder

Comment: Did you have any ideas?

Comment: @ZuzooVn extract the package and look where the files would be installed; or simply search: find / -iname libconfig\*