# Adding a custom library to c programs

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu Linux
I have made a custom static library Mylib.a, I can include it to only those c files which are in the same directory as the static library.

I want to make it a general library so that I can include the library file to any c file I want irrespective of its location

Comment: `gcc` will search in specific folders, see documentation for more details (you may start with `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable and also compile with `-v` to see where it search). Alternatively you may give full path (anywhere it is) on `gcc` command line.

Comment: How do you include this library? You have to include the header and link the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy that `.a` file (or better `.so` file) to a standard location such as `/usr/lib`.

If you compile from the command line, you also need to specify the library name (even if it's already in `/usr/lib`), the same way when you specify standard library like `-lpthread`.

You can also specify the library path and library name in [`makefile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519342/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-l-in-makefile)

Comment: I did copy it to /usr/lib but it still gives me compilation error

Comment: Is it link error or compilation error? Did you remember to copy the `.h` file to `/usr/include` as well?

Comment: I did not copy the .h file

Comment: It works! I still have to mention the library name when I run the object file    gcc -o ex ex.o -l_mylib
Is there a way to add this library permanently to a MakeFile

Comment: Is there a way to create a custom lib that can be called without the -l<namelib> ? (like -lpthread)

Comment: @artm Regarding "/usr/local/include" or "/usr/include", is there any reference of putting custom, user made H, HPP file location?

Answer (score 4):

To use a static library you have to include the header in the .c files that use the library and then link the library. If the name of the library is `libstatic.a` then:

```
gcc -o yourprog yourprog.c -lstatic
```

If the library is not in the same directory use the -L option to specify the path:

```
gcc -o yourprog yourprog.c -L/path-to-lib -lstatic
```

(see also this post: [How to link to a static library in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705961/how-to-link-to-a-static-library-in-c))

Answer (score 1):

As Adriano wrote, you can include a library even if it is not in the same directory as your c file. However, you have to specify where to look for for the libraries you use.

see here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html

Hope I helped,