# add FMOD libraries to QT

Tags: c++, qt, api, hyperlink, fmod

I am trying to add sounds to a qt project but when i try to link the library with the code:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Studio API Windows\api\lowlevel\inc"
LIBS += "C:\Program Files (x86)\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Studio API Windows\api\lowlevel\lib -libfmodex"
```

i get the following error :

```
error: C:\Program Files (x86)\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Studio API Windows\api\lowlevel\lib -libfmodex: No such file or directory
```

and if i use the following lines i get bunch of "undefined referece" errors

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Studio API Windows\api\lowlevel\inc"
LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Studio API Windows\api\lowlevel\lib -libfmodex"
```

i checked all other fmod related questions in stackoverflow but couldnt find any solution. can anyone please help me with this problem?

*QT creator 4.0.0
based on version 5.6,
fmod version 1.07.04*

Comment: *LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Studio API Windows\api\lowlevel\lib" -fmodL_vc.lib*

result is :  error: unrecognized command line option '-fmodL_vc.lib'

Comment: **SOLUTION**
this is what worked for me `win32{
    INCLUDEPATH += "D:\FMOD Studio API Windows\api\lowlevel\inc"
    DEPENDPATH  += "D:\FMOD Studio API Windows\api\lowlevel\inc"
    LIBS += -L"D:\FMOD Studio API Windows\api\lowlevel\lib" -lfmod_vc
}`

Answer (score 0):

LIBS += **-L**"C:/Program Files (x86)/FMOD SoundSystem/FMOD Studio API Windows/api/lowlevel/lib/**"** -**l**fmodex

Pay attention to **"** closing folder and NOT including `-lfmodex`

Also read this [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519342/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-l-in-makefile)

Comment: thank you for your comment but this is the result:
error: cannot find -lfmodex
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Sorry, I pointed to obvious syntax error, if you still have that error check if library actually exists there and post your **current** `LIBS+` statement

Comment: there is no lfmodex in the lib folder. libfmod.a, libfmodL.a...


this is the current line : LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Studio API Windows\api\lowlevel\lib" -lfmodex

Comment: There are also `fmod_vc.lib`,  `fmod64_vc.lib`, `fmodL_vc.lib` and `fmodL64_vc.lib` files. You need to link with one of them depending on your project configuration (32 or 64 bits?)

Comment: 32bits, i should choose fmod_vc_lib maybe?

Comment: From documentation: "fmod_vc.lib - Release 32-bit binary for production code", "fmodL_vc.lib - Release 32-bit binary with logging enabled for development". It seems you are currently at development stage...

Comment: i am not sure if i understand what that means.

Comment: I suggest you to use `fmodL_vc.lib` at the current stage because it will emit log records, which will be usful for further development and debugging. Please read documentaion