# mysql connector cpp in centos 6 undefined reference to

Tags: c++, mysql, centos, g++, connector

I already installed `mysql cpp connector` and `Boost` and also the g++ compiler.

When I write a program that uses the `mysql cpp connector` it gives me the error:

> demo.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to 'get_driver_instance'
>     collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

The command I'm using to build this code is:

```
g++ demo.cpp -o demo
```

My source code is :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   cout << endl;
   cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!'  AS _message'..." << endl;

   try {
      sql::Driver *driver;
      sql::Connection *con;
      sql::Statement *stmt;
      sql::ResultSet *res;

      /* Create a connection */
      driver = get_driver_instance();
      con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
      /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
      con->setSchema("test");

      stmt = con->createStatement();
      res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message"); // replace            with your statement
      while (res->next()) {
         cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
         /* Access column data by alias or column name */
         cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
         cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
         /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
         cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
      }
      delete res;
      delete stmt;
      delete con;
   }
   catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
      cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
      cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
      cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
      cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
      cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
   }

   cout << endl;

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Can anyone please suggest some solution to this?
I have already tried so many things but it didn't work.
Do I need to re-install everything?

I already followed the

> MySQL-connector installation steps

as described in MySQL's help.

Comment: Looks like a linker problem. `To use the static Connector/C++ library, link against two library files, libmysqlcppconn-static.a and libmysqlclient.a.` [source here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-apps-linux-netbeans.html). Or the dynamic library: `To use the Connector/C++ dynamic library, link your project with a single library file, libmysqlcppconn.so.`

Comment: already tried `mysql_driver.h` header-file but it gives conflicts in `get_driver_instance()` method call.

Comment: The problem is not about the header. It's a linker problem, so link the needed libraries.

Comment: sir i m using command line to run this code. can u suggest me how can i link library by command ?

Comment: Please edit your question and show your current `g++` command.

Comment: If you have the libraries installed this one should work: `g++ demo.cpp -o demo -lmysqlcppconn`

Comment: thank you very much sir. this command solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your current build command: `g++ demo.cpp -o demo` doesn't contain informations for the linker `ld` which libraries should be linked against. Because of that you get a linker error:

> demo.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to 'get_driver_instance'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

In [this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-apps-linux-netbeans.html) is written which libraries are needed.

You can either link static or dynamically.
**Static linking** means that your executable will run on machines that doesn't have the needed libraries installed as the libraries are inside the executable. This also makes the executable bigger in size. In the case of the MySQL Connector/C++ the libraries are: `libmysqlcppconn-static.a` and `libmysqlclient.a`
**Dynamic linking** means that your executable will need to find the libraries on the machine where it should run. The needed library is: `libmysqlcppconn.so`.

Your build command with **dynamic linking** (using `libmysqlcppconn.so`) should look like:

```
g++ demo.cpp -o demo -lmysqlcppconn
```

Further note the difference between `-l` and `-L`  as mentioned [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/519356/8051589) or [here in the official gcc linker documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html):

> `-L` is the path to the directories containing the libraries. A search path for libraries.
>
> `-l` is the name of the library you want to link to.

You dont need a path (`-L`) here as the libraries should lie under `/usr/local/lib` which is the default installation and is already in the search path of the linker.

Comment: Hi @Vasara if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try(Generated using eclipse):

```
Building file: ./stack.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/opt/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.7-linux-glibc2.5-x86-64bit/include - I/opt/boost_1_61_0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF "./stack.d" -MT "./stack.o" -o "./stack.o" "./stack.cpp"

Building target: mysqlExample
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -L/opt/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.7-linux-glibc2.5-x86-64bit/lib -o "mysqlExample" ./stack.o -lmysqlcppconn
```

and do change mysql-connector path with your's and file names.