# DSO missing from command line when compiling

Tags: c++, compilation, missing-symbols

I have seen here several posts with similar questions and tried many suggestions but still, I haven't found a way around my problem.
I use for my work some cpp codes that I have to slightly change according to my needs. They have their own makefile with the same structure. Those files use the same list of libraries and while I can compile some of them, for others the compilation is not successful. Specifically, I'm getting the following error:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: fill_worldqual_load.o: undefined reference to symbol 'mysql_free_result@@libmysqlclient_18'//usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

The makefile is this:

```
CC         = g++ -Wall -Wno-unused-but-set-variable
MAKE       = make -f makefile
APPNAME    = fill_worldqual_load
OBJECTS    = fill_worldqual_load.o ../general_function/timestring.o \
../general_function/country.o \
../general_function/general_functions.o \
../options/options.o options_fill_wq_load.o
CCOPTS     = -c
OPTIMIZE   = -O3

INCDIROPTS  = -L/usr/local/lib/libmysqlpp.so -I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so  -I/usr/local/include/mysql++ -I../general_function -I../options 
LNKLIB      = -lmysqlpp

$(APPNAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(INCDIROPTS) $(LNKOPTS) -o $(APPNAME) $(OBJECTS) $(LNKLIB) 

.cpp.o: 
    $(CC) -c $(INCDIROPTS) $(DEBUG) -o $*.o $*.cpp 

all:    clean 
    @$(MAKE) $(APPNAME)
    echo all: make complete
```

I have succesfully compiled similar codes with the same list of libraries and the same makefile structure. After calling ldd for one of those programs I get:

```
libmysqlpp.so.3 => /usr/local/lib/libmysqlpp.so.3
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
libmysqlclient.so.18 => //usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002aaffda12000)
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002aaffef79000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00002aafff195000)
libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00002aafff3ab000)
libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00002aafff61d000)
libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002aafffa7f000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00002aafffc83000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00002aafffed0000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00002ab0001b9000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00002ab0003bd000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00002ab0005f0000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00002ab000800000)
libresolv.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00002ab000a04000)
libselinux.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00002ab000c1d000)
libpcre.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00002ab000e44000)
```

If I understand well, this program succesfully linked libmysqlclient.so.18 but the program I first mentioned did not. I don't understand why. I really appreciate any hint!

Comment: You might be missing a linker flag. Try adding `-lmysqlclient` to `LINKLIB`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096807/dso-missing-from-command-line/24096911)  [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519342/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-l-in-makefile) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19905704/7431860) [helpful(?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25088623/7431860) [links.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-building-clients.html)

Comment: Thanks Nick! if I put that flag in LINKLIB then I got: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient  .... but the other codes also need mysqlclient and they compile without problem

Comment: Perhaps `-L/usr/lib64/mysql`? Your `INCDIROPTS` is wrong. You should specify directories where libraries can be found with `-L` and the actual library names with `-l`

Comment: Thanks Ted .. it solved the issue :) ... I just wondering why it was not a problem for the other codes also requiring mysqlclient .. thank you once again for your help!

Comment: @user286686 Glad it worked out. It's hard to say why the other projects worked. Perhaps something else made it link with those libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `INCDIROPTS` field is incorrect. In Makefiles, [library locations are specified with `-L` and the actual library names are linked with `-l`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/519356/7431860)

Specify the mysql library with `-L/usr/lib64/mysql` in `INCDIROPTS`, and then link it with `-lmysqlclient` in `LNKLIB`.